# htaccess return 404 instead of 200

Tags: .htaccess

I use this line in my htaccess file for returning index.html in any case of 404:

ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

that work but the file return in the browser with 404 code.

how can I change this line in my htaccess for return 200 code with the index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

`ErrorDocument` tells your httpd which document to send alongside the 404 error code. If you want to always send the `index.html` file, you can use `mod_rewrite`

Here is an example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html
```

This rewrites (internally) all requests that don't map to a file or directory to your `index.html` page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` directive you can use [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource):

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

As per manual about `FallbackResource`:

> Use this to set a handler for any URL that doesn't map to anything in your filesystem, and would otherwise return HTTP 404 (Not Found).